# New to Android.....Using Samsung Captivate for debugging

Tags: android

Just wondering I have searched but I have not found an answer. My question is I installed the latest sdk 4.0 platform. I am testing with a Samsung Captivate which runs on 2.2. When I debug I get the error about them being on different platforms. My question I quess is probably stupid, But can I ever use the captivate to test my apps I build in platform 4.0 or must I stay at the 2.2 level? New to this....Can I update my phone or just test using the 2.2 platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only be able to test apps that your phone supports.  You are able to target different versions of Android (in Eclipse, right mouse click on your project then edit the Project properties - target a lower version of the OS).

Bottom line, if you are writing apps that target a specific version (in your case you wrote something for 4.0) the device you use must support that version of the OS.

You can set the version you target, which will allow you to debug on your device.

Comment: To clarify, you can set your project to support 2.2, and it will still run on 4.0.  I don't think the answer made that clear.  You should of course test it on 4.0, as we've had some minor issues with client apps and ICS.